# Как вытащить значение за пределы функции js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

прошу помощи сам не разбираюсь, реально ли такое провернуть, вопрос возможно для кого то глупый. В коде отметил комментариями, буду благодарен если уделите вопросу немного своего времени, спасибо.

```
let thelamports = 3123123;/// Как мне получить значение сюда значение от connection.getBalance
let theWallet = "9m5kFDqgpf7Ckzbox91RYcADqcmvxW4MmuNvroD5H2r9"
function getWallet(){

    
}

const Content: FC = () => {
    let [lamports, setLamports] = useState(0);
    let [wallet, setWallet] = useState("9m5kFDqgpf7Ckzbox91RYcADqcmvxW4MmuNvroD5H2r9");

  
    

    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

    const onClick = useCallback( async () => {

        if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();
        connection.getBalance(publicKey).then((bal) => {
            console.log(bal/LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);// нужное значение выдается в консоль как его использовать за пределами этой функции, конкретно в переменной "thelamports"

        });

        console.log(publicKey.toBase58());
        console.log("lamports sending: {}", thelamports)
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({

                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                toPubkey: new PublicKey(theWallet),
                lamports: thelamports,
            })
        );

        const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);

        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
    }, [publicKey, sendTransaction, connection]);
```

Comment: А что будет, если вы в том месте, где пишете внутри функции комментарий, сделаете присваивание thelamports=что вы там в console.log печатаете

Comment: Кофе наливал, ошибка. Я сам не понимаю как работает этот код, он выдает результат getbalans в консоль, нужно что бы этот результат оказался в переменной, но я так понимаю за пределы onclick он не уходит либо условий if. я не особо понимаю синтаксис

Comment: Я ещё помню, как я сам учил JS. Думаю, у Вас все работает правильно, но не в том порядке, в котором Вы ожидаете. Джиэс же весь из себя асинхронный. И вот Ваша программа работает, но какое из присваиваний выполнится первым-за ранее непонятно. Ну, и важно верить, что чудес не бывает. Тогда все получится!

Comment: Примерно понял мысль, спасибо